# SQL Query Error: SQLDMO

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

The following is my SQL query which works fine on SQL server 2005, but on SQL Server 2008, it throws the error:

> sp_Security error: Unable to create SQLDMO Server object

**SQL Query:**

```
DECLARE @object int
DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @hack smallint
DECLARE @return varchar(255)
DECLARE @Results nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @server sysname
DECLARE @login sysname
DECLARE @tsql varchar(1500)

set @server = 'YOGESH\SQLEXPRESS'

EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'SQLDMO.SQLServer', @object OUT

IF @hr < 0
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('sp_Security error: Unable to create SQLDMO Server object', 0, 1)
   RETURN
END

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @object,'LoginSecure', 'False'

IF @hr < 0
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('sp_Security error: Unable to set LoginSecure', 0, 1)
   GOTO ExitProc
END

Print ' Security Audit for Server : ' + @server

set @tsql = 'DECLARE login_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT loginname FROM master.dbo.syslogins order by loginname' 

exec (@tsql)

OPEN login_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM login_cursor
INTO @login

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   set @hack = 0
   set @Results = 'Connect("' + @server +'","'+@login+'","'+@login+'")'

   EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @object, @Results

   IF @hr = 0
   begin
      print 'login : ' + @login + ' security problem with password ' + @login
      EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @object, 'Disconnect'

      set @hack = 1
   end

   IF (@hack = 0)
   begin
     set @Results = 'Connect("' + @server +'","'+@login+'","'+'")'

     EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @object, @Results

     IF @hr = 0
     begin
        print 'login : ' + @login + ' security problem with password NULL'

        EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @object, 'Disconnect'

        set @hack = 1
     end
   end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: A [similar question on SQLDMO in SqlServer 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875145/sql-server-2008-alternative-for-sql-dmo) was posted (and answered) in 2010.  See [Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referenced in the comment from hardmath, Microsoft no longer distributes SQL-DMO libraries with SQL Server 2008 in favor of SQL SMO. Even so, you can still install SQL-DMO via 'Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Backward Compatibility Components' (you can find download links for that package on [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16177)).

Here is an alternate way to enable SQL Server logins that does not use SQL-DMO:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
GO
```

I suspect that the above code will not work on versions of SQL Server prior to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Nice, you've packed several useful tidbits in one answer!